# How to trace all methods in an application

Tags: c#, .net, logging, reflection

Do you know how to trace all method invocations in an .NET application. My current approach is to write trace at the beginning of each method like this

```
void DoSomething()
{
   using(new Tracer(TraceCategory)
{
   //Perform all action here

}

}
```

But it sucks as it clusters my code and I will have to write traces for all of my method.

Would there another way to record when a method is called, and when it finishes? All suggestions would be appreciate.

Comment: This can be done from a .NET profiler. You can write your own (fairly complex task but a lot easier for .NET than it is for native code) or get an existing one that supports tracing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only practical option to implement this I know of is to use AOP (like postsharp) - for a nice walkthrough see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/337564/Aspect-Oriented-Programming-Using-Csharp-and-PostS).

Answer (score 3):

You should use frameworks like Unity or PostSharp. Both of them have hooks for before method starting and after method finishing events.

[Sample for Unity](http://www.alexthissen.nl/blogs/main/archive/2009/03/25/using-unity-to-do-poor-man-s-tracing.aspx)

Sample for PostSharp was already posted by Yahia.

Comment: In Unity,do you know what the events are? Could you provide some links?

Comment: Given link not working. Here is the new one: https://alexthissen.wordpress.com/2009/03/25/using-unity-to-do-poor-mans-tracing/